# problem applying a function to a list in R

Tags: r

I have created a function that converts "YYYYQQ" to integer YYYYMMDD. The function works well with individual values in a list but not on the whole list. I am not unable to understand the warning message.

```
GetProperDate <- function(x) {
     x <- as.character(x)
     q<-substr(x, 5, 6)
     y<-substr(x, 1,4) %>% as.numeric()
      if(q=="Q1"){
         x <- as.integer(paste0(y,"03","31"))
  }
        if(q=="Q2"){
            x <- as.integer(paste0(y,"06","30"))
  }
        if(q=="Q3"){
            x <- as.integer(paste0(y,"09","30"))
  }
        if(q=="Q4"){
           x <- as.integer(paste0(y,"12","31"))
          }       
  return(x)
}

> GetProperDate("2019Q1")
[1] 20190331
> GetProperDate("2019Q2")
[1] 20190630
> GetProperDate("2019Q3")
[1] 20190930
> GetProperDate("2019Q4")
[1] 20191231
> date.list<-c("2019Q1","2019Q2","2019Q3","2019Q4")
> date.list.converted<- date.list %>% GetProperDate()
Warning messages:
1: In if (q == "Q1") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (q == "Q2") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (q == "Q3") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (q == "Q4") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> date.list.converted
[1] 20190331 20190331 20190331 20190331
>
```

As shown above  I am getting a warning message and the output is not as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
GetProperDate <- function(x) {
  x <- as.character(x)
  q <- substr(x, 5, 6)
  y <- substr(x, 1,4) %>% 
    as.numeric()
  x <- case_when(
    q=="Q1" ~ as.integer(paste0(y,"03","31")), 
    q =="Q2" ~ as.integer(paste0(y,"06","30")), 
    q == "Q3" ~ as.integer(paste0(y,"09","30")), 
   TRUE ~ as.integer(paste0(y,"12","31")))
  return(x)
}
```

```
date.list<-c("2019Q1","2019Q2","2019Q3","2019Q4")
GetProperDate(date.list) 

>  GetProperDate(date.list) 
[1] 20190331 20190630 20190930 20191231
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you have written a function `GetProperDate` which is not vectorised. `if` is used for scalar inputs and not vector. You may switch to `ifelse` which is vectorised and rewrite your function.

Apart from that you can also use `as.yearqtr` from `zoo`  which is used to handle quarterly dates and get the last date of the quarter by using `frac = 1`.

```
as.Date(zoo::as.yearqtr(date.list), frac = 1)
#[1] "2019-03-31" "2019-06-30" "2019-09-30" "2019-12-31"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a vector to the function,it is comparing vector with a scalar. R automatically takes the first element of the vector. thats why you get warning as the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used..Try this

```
date.list<-c("2019Q1","2019Q2","2019Q3","2019Q4")
date.list.converted <- sapply(date.list, function(s) GetProperDate(s))
```